# Array nested in hash for WP API?

Tags: ruby, wordpress, xml-rpc

Here's my call:

```
 result = blog.call('wp.newPost',
                   1,
                   'user',
                   'pw',
                   { 
                     'post_type' => 'post', 
                     'post_content' => entry[3], 
                     'post_name' => entry[2].downcase.split(" ").join("-"),
                     'comment_status' => 'closed',
                     'pinged' => 'closed',
                     'post_status' => 'publish',
                     'post_title' => entry[2],
                     'terms' => ['category' => 9]
                   })
```

This is returning an error that this post type `post` doesn't support one of the taxonomies given `category` - well, every post should have a category, so I'm thinking that my ruby is malformed. The API asks for an array with the taxonomy as a key and its ID as the value, which I think I've done here.

This is for v3.4 - [here is the documentation on wp.newPost](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.newPost)

Comment: Hard to comment without seeing the `blog.call` method. But, the API documentation asks for an array with taxonomy names as keys and an array of term ids as values. So, I'm guessing it should be `'terms' => ['category' => [9]]` if `9` is the ID of the term you want to assign to the post.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with Ruby, but I don't think you can specify array keys in that language so you may need to use a hash instead: `'terms' => {'category' => [9]}`

Comment: @RichardM both of those didn't work, actually - and I do think it has something to do with the array format. The first one yielded the same error and the second one yielded a 302 found error (it ignored that line completely basically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the following code worked:

```
    blogcontent = {
        :post_type => 'post',
        :post_content => entry[3],
        :post_name => entry[2].downcase.split(" ").join("-"), 
        :comment_status => 'closed', 
        :pinged => 'closed',
        :post_status => 'publish',
        :post_title => entry[2],
        :terms =>
            {
                :category => [9]
            }
  }
```

This converted (via the XMLRPC Writer) to the appropriate XML and registered the posts in WordPress. Turning on the XML-RPC debugging information revealed that a struct wasn't being passed unless the variable `9` was enclosed in brackets, even though it is a single value array.